# How to implement a captcha ?

Tags: forms, ce-1.6.2.0

How can I implement a captcha in my custom form?

Actually I have installed a forum module where I need to implement a captcha for preventing spam.

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="messageForm" method="post">
  <input name="title" id="title" title="<?php echo $this->__('Title') ?>" value="<?php echo $this->__('RE : %s',$this->htmlEscape($this->topic->getTitle())) ?>"  />
  <textarea name="content" id="content" title="<?php echo $this->__('Message') ?>" value="" class="required-entry"></textarea>
  <button class="button" type="submit"><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var messageForm = new VarienForm('messageForm', true);
  </script>
```

Comment: This question is fairly broad. Are you looking for a programmatic solution? Please be more specific.

Comment: I am not looking for detailed answer containing all code. Just looking the best approach for implementing Captcha in MAGENTO.

Comment: Please update your question with information on how you created your custom form?

Comment: Captchas are not worth to implement. Did you try to add a new text field, style it with display: none and check wether something is in it? If yes, it is spam. Captchas are extremly annoying and easy to solve, often by computers, if not by paid humans. And in magento 1.7 there is the option to have captchas in the customer registration.

Comment: As others have commented you need to provide more information on what elements you want to protect with a Captcha. Eg. Contact form, checkout etc

Comment: As I already Stated I want to use captcha validation for My Custom form used in a "forum"  module(Magento Extension for implementing forum functionality). The form consist of only three text type input field (Name, Title and Message).

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt..Thanks for the suggesting me a new approach. But It will not work here because the client just want to show captcha validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (your client) must go with CAPTCHA, why not backport the [CE 1.7.0.2 `Mage_Captcha` module [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/tree/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha)?

I believe you could user your form view's full action name layout update handle and an `<update />` directive to reuse some of the [module's layout updates](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/captcha.xml#L31) for your form. You might want to add an appropriate configuration xpath to [set the title for your usage](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml#L221).

Comment: Back port?  How about upgrade!  :)

Answer (score 2):

Visit this link for details, it solved my problem; hope it helps someone.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/view./viewthread/298363/

If you are using "RWD" theme copy captcha.xml from base/default/layout to your_rwd_theme/default/layout. This is necessary as rwd themes design have this shortfall.

Quick outline how to add Magento builtin captcha mechanism to Contact Us default page.

1) To add Contact Us form to Admin/Config interface you could 
 a) find captcha/forms element in core_config table and add “contact_form” form name to the list 
 b) modify config.xml in /app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc 
 in `- <frontend> - <areas>` add something like

```
<contact_form>
    <label>Contact Us</label> 
</contact_form>
```

and in - `<always_for>`

`<contact_form>1</contact_form>`

Also there’s a miss for translation in the config file, so you should add this to the `<frontend>` section:

```
<translate>
 <modules>
 <Mage_Captcha>
 <files>
  <default>Mage_Captcha.csv</default> 
  </files>
  </Mage_Captcha>
  </modules>
 </translate>
```

Refresh cache. Login to Admin, and make sure Contact Us form is listed in CAPTCHA configuration

2) Modify captcha layout xml file in frontend/base/default (or your theme) 
 add this section

```
<contacts_index_index>
 <reference name="contactForm">
 <block type="core/text_list" name="form.additional.info">
 <block type="captcha/captcha" name="captcha">
 <reference name="head">
  <action method="addJs">
  <file>mage/captcha.js</file> 
  </action>
  </reference>
  <action method="setFormId">
  <formId>contact_form</formId> 
  </action>
 <action method="setImgWidth">
  <width>230</width> 
  </action>
<action method="setImgHeight">
  <width>50</width> 
  </action>
  </block>
  </block>
  </reference>
  </contacts_index_index>
```

Refresh cache

3) Modify form code in /frontend/base/default/template/contacts/form.phtml to add placeholder to render captcha layout 
 Add this line of code right before `</ul>`

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>`

4) FInal part - how to\\"trap\\" the post from the Contact Us form and check the captcha 
 Mage uses Events and Observer to achieve this, and it works very well for the forms/events they have implemented this feature. I was not able to find events specific for Contact Us form, so, IMHO the most obvious solution is to override indexController in code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers and in the postAction method, inside try block add the following code:

```
$formId = 'contact_form';
           $captchaModel = Mage::helper('captcha')->getCaptcha($formId);
           if ($captchaModel->isRequired()) {
            if (!$captchaModel->isCorrect($this->_getCaptchaString($this->getRequest(), $formId))) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('captcha')->__('Incorrect CAPTCHA.'));
                $this->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl(''));
                return;
            }
           }
```

and add this \\"utility method to the controller class:

```
protected function _getCaptchaString($request, $formId)
    {
        $captchaParams = $request->getPost(Mage_Captcha_Helper_Data::INPUT_NAME_FIELD_VALUE);
        return $captchaParams[$formId];
    }
```

5) Refresh cache, and give it a try

Comment: It would have been better if you have summarized here, whatever useful information have you got from that link :)

Comment: add brief things of content in the provided link and then add link a your reference and BTW welcome to MSE :)

Answer (score -1):

## How to add new form to CAPTCHA settings?

Create new module and add lines to config.xml

## How to show CAPTCHA in contacts form?

Find your form template and insert code.

After that find layout xml for your page, for example mine was contacts.xml

## How to check CAPTCHA?

Create Observer for your module.